# Change directory for app which is installed via pip

Tags: django, pip

I'm using virtualenv and pip. Is it possible to move an app which is installed via pip out of virtualenv and into my django app folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes. Just move the corresponding folder from your virtualenv to your project folder along with your own apps.

However, the real question here is *why* you wanted to do something like that. Most users do this in order to actually change something in the source tree of the external application to suite their needs. Most of the time this is *not* the correct thing to do and contradicts the [django philosophy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/misc/design-philosophies/). Use it only as a last resort and even then I believe it is better to fork the project, do your changes and propose a merge with the original project if it actually improves it.

**Update**

Here's what I'd do specifically for [django-lazysignup](https://github.com/danfairs/django-lazysignup): First of all I'd create an application named `lazysignup_override` and include this (along with the `lazysignup` application) in my `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Now, you say you want to override the templates and he views of `lazysignup`:
The templates can be overriden if you create a folder named `lazysignup` in the templates folder of `lazysignup_override` and copy there the modified template files. Now, from what I see django-lazysignup defines only one view (unfortuanately *not* a CBV) that is used through the `urls.py`. So in the `lazysignup_override` folder you'd need to create a `views.py` that will contain your modified view and a `urls.py` with that view.

Finally, in the main `urls.py` of your project you'd add the line

```
urlpatterns += (''
    (r'^convert/', include('lazysignup_override.urls')),
)
```

(and add the  `lazysignup.backends.LazySignupBackend` to your `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`.

The above may seem like a lot of work however this is the correct way to go to be compatible with the philosophy (loose coupling, DRY etc). Also, if `lazysignup` was using CBVs then you can understand that overriding it would be much easier.

Comment: The use of the templates from django-lazysignup didn't suit my needs. So I made some changes to the view und templates. However, when I'm setting up a new dev environment I'm forced to do the changes again. So I thought it'd be nice to have the app in my django folder.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I'll implement it that way.